# ThreadPoolExecutor taking the same time as it was taking without it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, api, python-requests

In this code, I am reading a CSV containing 2000 entries. CSV contains data to hit the API.
The api_hit() function is in processing_chunks function.

slice_device_list() dividing the data in 20 chunks of each from 2000 entries and then I am using the thread_pool_executor with max_chunks  = 20 so that it can loop on those 20 chunks and call the api for each chunk with using thread. Bu I didn't get any improvement.

Here is the code that I am using:-

```
with open('/home/kapilsharma/Downloads/smpa_replace (1).csv', 'r') as read_object:
csv_reader = reader(read_object)

# to ignore the heading row
next(csv_reader)
try:
    # storing rows in list
    for row in csv_reader:
        list.append(row)

    #logger.info("Data read from csv :: {}".format(list))

    # dividing the list into 20-20 chunk, this would be 3-D array
    data_chunks = slice_device_list(list)

    try:
        for chunks in data_chunks:
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as exe:
                logger.info("Started executing...")
                exe.submit(processing_chunks, chunks)
                logger.info("Execution completed...")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Error occurred while hitting the api :: {}".format(e))


except Exception as ex:
    logger.info('Exception occurred in main part :: {}'.format(ex))
```

Is there any mistake in it that I am doing because the code is taking the same time as it was taking before without threading to hit the API for 2000 enteries.

Here is the processing_chunks() function:-

```
# Function to process the chunks
def processing_chunks(chunks):
    # Hitting the api
    for chunk in chunks:
        serial_no = chunk[1]
        oneCloudUserId = chunk[0]

        # Checking if deviceId exists in device table
        crsr.execute('select deviceId from device where serialNo = %s', (serial_no,))
        deviceId = crsr.fetchone()
        logger.info("deviceId :: {}".format(deviceId))

        # If deviceId not exists
        if deviceId == None:
            logger.info("Device not exist in CHP DB")
            # fields = ['x_user_id', 'serial_number', 'newService', 'Error']

            # Writing error in csv_file
            with open('false_api_hit2', 'a') as csvfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                row = [chunk[0], chunk[1], chunk[2], "Device not exist in CHP DB"]
                csvwriter.writerow(row)

        # If deviceId exists
        else:
            # Check deviceId and Xid(userId) combination exist in subscriptionInfo table
            # crsr.execute('select * from subscriptionInfo where deviceId=%s and oneCloudUserId=%s and cloudServiceName=%s', (deviceId[0], oneCloudUserId, "armor"))
            # row = crsr.fetchone()

            crsr.execute(
                'select serviceId, expiryDate, serviceType from subscriptionInfo where deviceId = %s and oneCloudUserId=%s and cloudServiceName=%s',
                (deviceId[0], oneCloudUserId, "armor"))
            row1 = crsr.fetchone()

            # If the combination does not exist
            if (row1 == None):
                logger.info('Device and User mapping not exist in subscriptionInfo')
                # Writing error in csv_file
                with open('false_api_hit2', 'a') as csvfile:
                    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                    row = [chunk[0], chunk[1], chunk[2], "Device and User mapping not exist in subscriptionInfo"]
                    csvwriter.writerow(row)


            # If the combination exists then hit the api
            else:
                service_id = row1[0]
                expiry_date = row1[1]
                service_type = row1[2]
                api_hit(chunk, service_id, str(expiry_date), service_type, deviceId[0])
```

And here is the api_hit() function:-

```
    def api_hit(data_chunks, service_id, expiry_date, service_type, deviceId):
    '''
    Function to hit the SMPA api
    :param data_chunks: chunk of data that we will get
    :return:
    '''

    try:
        try:
            payload = info
            # Updating payload
            payload["params"]["x_user_id"] = data_chunks[0]
            payload["params"]["reason"]["serial_number"] = data_chunks[1]
            payload["params"]["subscription"]["new_service"] = data_chunks[2]

            if (data_chunks[3] != ''):
                payload["params"]["reason"]["reason"] = data_chunks[3]

            payload["params"]["reason"]["comment"] = data_chunks[4]
            payload["params"]["subscription"]["service_id"] = service_id
            payload["params"]["subscription"]["expiry_date"] = expiry_date
            payload["params"]["subscription"]["service_type"] = service_type


        except Exception as ep:
            logger.info("Error occurred while updating payload :: {}".format(ep))

        try:
            # getting header to hit the api by calling function getWsseHeader
            HEADERS_VALUE = getWsseHeader("602a12-475e-4dc0-9d05",
                                          "BUZRKypEGGHansseAWWzDxhCk5lj9STV8i2WX")
            header = {"X-WSSE": HEADERS_VALUE}
        except Exception as eh:
            logger.info("Error occurred while getting header :: {}".format(eh))

        # Hitting api
        try:
            response = requests.request("POST", API_URL, json=payload, headers=header)
            response.raise_for_status()
            response = response.json()
            logger.info("Payload :: {}".format(payload))

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
            logger.info("Error occurred while getting response :: {}".format(error))
        except Exception as er:
            logger.info("Error while getting response :: {}".format(er))

        if response["result"]["status"] == 1:
            # fields = ['x_user_id', 'serial_number', 'newService', 'Error']

            # Writing error in csv_file
            with open('false_api_hit2', 'a') as csvfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                row = [data_chunks[0], data_chunks[1], data_chunks[2], response['result']['reason']]
                csvwriter.writerow(row)

        # status of response = 0 means success response
        elif response["result"]["status"] == 0:

            # Writing in csv_file
            # fields = ['x_user_id', 'serial_number', 'newService']
            with open('true_api_hit2', 'a') as csvfile:
                csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
                row = [data_chunks[0], data_chunks[1], data_chunks[2]]
                csvwriter.writerow(row)

            now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
            # SMPA gives success reponse then update newService in - subscriptionInfo 'service' column
            crsr.execute('UPDATE subscriptionInfo SET service = %s, modifiedAt = %s where deviceId = %s and oneCloudUserId=%s and cloudServiceName=%s',
                         (data_chunks[2], now, deviceId, data_chunks[0], "armor"))

            now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
            # if 'serviceId' exists in the response then update this in subscriptionInfo table and if it is not there then do nothing
            if "serviceId" in response["result"]:
                crsr.execute('UPDATE subscriptionInfo SET serviceId = %s, modifiedAt = %s where deviceId = %s and oneCloudUserId=%s and cloudServiceName=%s',
                             (response.result.serviceId, now, deviceId,data_chunks[0], "armor"))
            sql_connection.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        logger.info("Some error occurred as :: {}".format(e))
```

Function getWsseHeader() will return the header for the api call.

Comment: First, you have to determine if `processing_chunks` is an IO bound task or a CPU bound task?

Comment: @Corralien Sir, in processing_chunks function , I am calling api_hit() function. I have edited the question and included api_hit() function in that.

Comment: Try to replace `ThreadPoolExecutor` by `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Corralien It didn't work, this time it didn't execute for all the entries in csv, but only for 20.

Comment: `ProcessPoolExecutor` can be executed with `.map(...)` instead of `.submit(...)`.

Comment: @Corralien Tried but it is not calling the API now and the program stops running in 7 seconds unexpectedly, without calling the API.

Answer (score 1):

Like Corralien suggested, your first attempt has to be to determine whether `processing_chunks` is I/O-bound or CPU-bound.

For CPU-bound tasks, one can generally improve performance using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` which span the computing among multiple CPU cores you have to.

For I/O-bound tasks, you are basically out of luck. `ProcessPoolExecutor` only spawns more processes waiting for the chance to read or write the same file.

Due to [Python's GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), threads in Python are merely a way to schedule multiple pieces of programs to run in time slices. Threading doesn't automatically improve speed.

I'm guessing the bottleneck in `processing_chunks` is a combination of database operation (which leads to disk I/O) and network operation (in `requests`). And since you said the times are the same, I assume the network part is local. Threading might improve speed only when your network part is very slow.

Some additional readings:

- [Python multithreading in IO-bound tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777948/python-multithreading-in-io-bound-tasks)
- [Does multithreading make sense for IO-bound operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902425/does-multithreading-make-sense-for-io-bound-operations)