# Procedures to Trigger Continuously

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, service

I am working on a project. The project is to constantly check the sites that users will visit (such as checking every 3 minutes). I created my project from 2 different services. One is the service that will communicate with the user (I developed it with NodeJS). The other is a Python service that will perform background checks and write the necessary status notifications to the database.

I think Python is strong in this regard with its libraries. The issue I'm stuck on is this: suppose users enter too many addresses after a certain time. In this case, how can I do the control at the same time?

The first thing that came to my mind was thread and I created the following solution;

```py
threads = []

for website in websites:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=check, args=(website[0],website[1],website[2],))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

This code checks 200 URL addresses (test data) registered in the database. It uses `Thread` to control it at the same time, but since it uses too many `Threads` here, I think it is against the use of `Thread`. In short, I think there should be a healthier method of this method. Which path should I follow in this case? What methods do I need to modify and work on?

Thanks.

Comment: Your task seems to be IO bound, meaning Input-Output bound. This type of task contrasts with tasks that are CPU-bound. You can learn about the difference in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777948/python-multithreading-in-io-bound-tasks. 
I'd recommend the concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor API but feel free to listen to other recommendations as well.

Comment: @bantix Thank you for your suggestion. I can manage it with ThreadPoolExecutor as you suggested, but after a certain period of time, that is, after a certain number of transactions, the transactions will still be blocked. Even though it was not a problem at first, I think I will have problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In short, I think there should be a healthier method of this method. Which path should I follow in this case? What methods do I need to modify and work on?

In my view, a more scalable solution would involve implementing a task queue, considering the inherent limitations of a single computer's processing capacity. For example, if each instance of the service can handle up to 200 URLs simultaneously, and we have a total of 800 URLs to check, we can segment these URLs into batches of 200 and leverage a tool like Celery to distribute the workload efficiently.

given the nature of network operations involved, each worker should implement parallelism techniques, such as threads or coroutines, to maximize performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I started the project, I actually thought that I could solve it with certain methods at this stage, but I need to do some more work. As you said, I will have to continue with a certain technique by dividing the addresses. I need to create a custom algorithm for this.

PS: If there is no better answer, I will confirm it as an answer in 24 hours.